# WinAppDriver for desktop and webapp

Tags: c#, selenium, ui-testing, winappdriver

I’ve used Selenium for our gui-test and it works. 
But we have some webapps that when user click
on a link, a Word file opens that contains some 
data and has a small webapp (embedded) in the Word document. That webapp communicates with Word.
Is it possible to combine my Selenium tests with
WinAppDriver in the same test?

Comment: Since winappdriver is derived from selenium, there is a chance both can coexist in one project. Be sure to let SO know if it's doable, I'm interested :-). You can also try to call your compiled winappdriver test script exe from your selenium test script. Please note you'll have to develop your winappdriver test script in a separate solution if you would like to resolve your problem that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to click the second popup which you mentioned later in comments, try using a desktop session. Find the popup window first and then the child button and call click method as shown below.

```
sessionDesktop.FindElementByName("Alert").FindElementByName("OK").Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to keep both Appium and Selenium in one solution. I've automated the testing of an Excel Add-In using WinAppDriver, the same solution contains tests which open Chrome using Selenium.
I've used page/object model to keep concerns separate. The page factory class is responsible for creating and returning suitable objects in my solution, the map objects it returns are the ones that have either Selenium or Appium stuff hidden behind method calls.

Comment: Hi, so I tried a bit today and it worked. Now I must learn how to handle multiple windows.

Comment: That is easy, you will have two separate instances of IWebDriver.  One will be WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> and the other will be ChromeDriver or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Hi Naeem, in my app I start with session Internet Explorer. Then in IE I click on link that starts a Word document ( focus is set on that Word document). How can I switch to Word so I can sendKeys to it?

Comment: Use the method call SwitchTo to switch over to the Word window. If the Word document. Please mark this as an answer if the problem mentioned was solved.

Comment: Hi Naeem, I tried with SwitchTo but no luck. So my scenario: Start internet Explorer, navigator to URL, click on link that opens a Word document. A popup dialog shows that ask if you want to Edit document. Click yes. When Word document is opened, i click close Word document. The scenario works to this point. But when I try to switch to Word dialog box (popup) if I want to save doc. WinAppDriver tries to click in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Which session are you using to find the last popup? Try using a desktop session. Find the popup window in desktop and then find it's children. Let me put the code below in another answer.